# Extracting US dollar amount

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, match

This question has been asked before but I am still not able to make this work entirely.  I have the following examples of strings:

```
"Transfer to Retirement Rsvs-MA FX                   .11"                
"Opening Balance                FX        342,536,002.63"     
"VA                 85.85"               
"VB                   .00"     
"Manual Adjustment              FX              6,838.36-"
```

I would like to extract the US dollar/cents amount from the strings into a separate column of a dataframe.  I have the following regex expression:

```
rx = (r"(\$?(?:\d+,)*\d+\.\d+\-?)")
```

and I tried to create a column in the dataframe (df) called "dollars"

```
df2['dollars']=df2['description'].str.extract(rx)
```

It works for the most part, except for values like .11 or .00, in which case nan is returned.  How do I revise this expression to make it work for cents without leading dollars?

Help with this is greatly appreciated!

```
string                                                       dollars
Transfer to Retirement Rsvs-MA FX                   .11      0.11
Opening Balance                FX        342,536,002.63      342,536,002.63
VA                    85.85                                  85.85
VB                   .00                                     .00
Manual Adjustment FX 6,838.36-                               6,836-
```

Comment: Try `r'\$?(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d{4,})?\.?\d+'`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YIDwcT/1).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thank you!  This worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\$?(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d{4,})?\.?\d+'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YIDwcT/1)

**Details**

- `\$?` - an optional `$` char
- `(?<!\d)` - make sure there is no digit immediately to the left
- `(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d{4,})?` - either of the two patterns:

  - `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*` - 1 to 3 digits followed with 0 or more occurrences of a comma and three digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{4,}` - four or more digits
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

Answer (score 1):

You might use:

```
(?<!\S)\$?(?:\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*)?\.\d{2}-?(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Whitespace boundary on the left
- `\$?` Optional dollar sign
- `(?:\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*)?` Optional part matching 1-3 digits optionally repeated by comma and 3 digits
- `\.\d{2}` Match a `.` and 2 digits
- `-?` Optional hyphen
- `(?!\S)` Whitespace boundary on the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Rl6pJ/1)

If you want 1+ digits after the dot, change `\.\d{2}` to `\.\d+`